# How to fix UI unresponsiveness if requesting the Users Location in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to request a users location for my native iOS app. It works fine when the user accepts but if he denies the request and goes back to the map screen (which also works without the user location, but some functions need it) the debugger shows the error

```
This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.
```

I know that there are multiple questions like this. But all answers are pre-iOS 17, use UIKit or don't solve my problem. So I had a look at them but the answers did not help me.

Currently my Location Manager looks like this

```swift
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func requestAuthorization() {
        print("requestAuthorization called")
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
              if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                  self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
              }
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.authorizationStatus = status
    }
}
```

After searching on the internet I found out that apparently this CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled causes the issue. I tried moving it off the main thread and I still have the same issue. I also tried the location manager and leaving CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled out and just trying to request the location. This also did not solve the issue. I now that the error message tells me what to do but I don't understand it. I haven't found a code example in which I did not have this issue.
My View calls

```swift
.onAppear{
            if locationManager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                locationManager.requestAuthorization()
            }
        }
```

I would expect that if a user has denied the request that the UI is still responsive and I did not get this error. I want to use the authorizationStatus variable in the LocationManager to show an Alert if the user has not accepted.

Comment: FWIW, in WWDC 2021 video [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290), they advise isolating the `ObservableObject` to the main actor. E.g. `@MainActor class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {…}`. And, again, make sure you have no dispatches to background queues.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you for your help. Here please have a look at that [image](https://imgur.com/a/bzfP7EZ). I think that is what you meant. If I don't put it in a DispatchQueue I just always have the error.

Beforehand I just had it when denying the location request and coming back to the view where it is requested. As you can see in the screenshot I added the `@MainActor` and left out the dispatch queue. I tried using the DispatchQueue because the error says "This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. [...]".

Comment: What that message is saying is not to use that property *at all*. You can wait for the callback to your location manager delegate that delivers the authorisation status. In your code there is no real need for the `if`; just request permission. if permission has previously been denied then nothing happens. If the user hasn't been asked for permission previously then the dialog will be shown.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 thank you. I also tried to leave out the `if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` but then I still have the error message if permission is denied and the user navigates to the view which uses the location. If permission was given I never encounter the error. Only if previously denied. The app still functions as it should but I get this error in the console.

Comment: If you absolutely feel the need to call `locationServicesEnabled` (we generally don’t, and just look at the `authorizationStatus`, but do whatever you want), fine, do that in the detached task (or background queue if you have not yet adopted Swift concurrency). But the call to `CLLocationManager` method `requestAuthorization` must take place on main actor (or, again, the main queue if you have not yet adopted Swift concurrency).

Comment: I meant leave out the `if locationManager.authoizationStatus == .notDetermined`. You don't need it. Just call `requestAuthorization` regardless.

Comment: @Rob That’s not what I meant. I’ll happily leave out .locationServicesEnabled. I was just saying that even if I leave it out I still get the error when location authorization is denied. I’m a Uni student and in this semester our project is a native app. So Iam not super deep into swift. So I can definitely use your recommendations.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for making it clearer, so I don’t save resources checking if I actually have to request the authorization? I left the if out and still got the issue.

Comment: I personally have a switch statement on `locationManager.authorizationStatus` which will `requestAuthorization` if currently `.notDetermined`, will put up a little alert offering to take them to settings if `.denied`, proceed as normal if already approved, etc. Personally, it seems weird to `requestAuthorization` if it was already approved or already denied (assuming the user initiated something where location services are essential). But, that having been said, if already approved/denied, requesting again is a NOP, so I guess it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Rob The switch statement makes sense to me. I have tried this at the beginning then i tried different solutions to get rid of the error. But does the rest of my code look fine? Because I cannot find the solution to the error. Different question, but how do you then show the alert. Currently I have the authorizationStatus variable in my Location Manager and in my view I check on appear if it’s denied and show an alert. That’s probably a stupid solution but I haven’t found a better one.

Comment: @Rob It’s this error „This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.“

Comment: But if you removed the `if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() { … }`, what line is giving you that error?

Comment: @Rob basically it doesn't really show anywhere it makes sense. Here the [image](https://imgur.com/a/u9THrqq) It shows on the body App file.

Comment: Run a build->clean.

Comment: @Paulw11 I did. Also completely deleted the app from my phone and tried again. Same issue

Comment: I tried to narrow it down and created a new project just with the Map and the location manager. Here is the [code](https://pastebin.com/QPc0TF3M). I also get this issue here

Comment: Perhaps empty derived data folder and then restart Xcode.

Comment: Error is still there. But thank you so much for trying.

Comment: @Rob Maybe one of these warnings give more insight? I don't understand them

CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x283a3c800>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x280a353b0> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"


Missing MeshRenderables for ground mesh layer for (2/2) of ground tiles. Tile debug info: (Key: 8.5.4.255 t:33 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 2, PendingMaterial count: 2, Invisible MeshInstances count: 0 | Key: 8.4.4.255 t:33 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 2, PendingMaterial count: 2, Invisible MeshInstances count: 0)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to guard your calls to location authorisation requests.  You can just ask;

- if the user hasn't been asked for permission before, then the permission dialog will be shown
- If the user has previously been asked for permission and responded to the dialog, nothing is shown to the user.

If you do want to avoid some unnecessary permission request calls then you can use the `authorizationStatus` property that you already have.

There is no need to check explicitly for location services being enabled; again, if they are disabled then then permission request will do nothing.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func requestAuthorization() {
        print("requestAuthorization called")
        guard self.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined else {
            return
        }
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.authorizationStatus = status
    }
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
.onAppear {
    locationManager.requestAuthorization()
}
```

To improve the user experience you may want to provide feedback in your UI where location permission has been denied and offer guidance on opening settings to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. That’s how I am currently doing it. The issue with the UI unresponsiveness error still persists.

Comment: On which line is the error shown?

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/u9THrqq). I don't know why it is shown there but it just occurs if the location is denied and I go back to that view.

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI `Map`?  It may well be Apple's own code that is causing the message. It is a warning that you can ignore.

Comment: Yes I use the swift ui map like [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/). So I cannot do anything about it? Do you also get the same error?

Comment: I've never tried using the map with denied location status. I will see if I have time to do a quick test later